# Qt Bluetooth Low Energy Multiple Connections

Tags: linux, qt, bluetooth-lowenergy

*Qt: 5.10,*
*Linux Ubuntu 17.10,*
*Bluez 5.4x*

and I´m using QBluetooth to connect with multiple Bluetooth Low Energy Devices. Everything works fine for one Connection. But when I connect to a second Device with *QLowEnergyController::connectToDevice()* I get the following error and the first Connection gets aborted:

```
qt.bluetooth.bluez: Cannot connect due to pending active LE Connections
qt.bluetooth.bluez: void QBluetoothSocketPrivate::_q_readNotify() 21 error: -1 "Software caused Connection abort"
```

After that the second connection gets established.

I`m using one instance of QLowEnergyController in **Central Mode** per Connection.

After a Research I think it should be possible to create multiple Connections to BLE Peripherals with the Bluez Bluetooth Protocol Stack. But I´m not sure if QBluetooth support this Feature...

1. Does anybody know something about multiple LE Connections with QBluetooth?
2. Is this the right way to establish a second Connection?
3. Does somebody know a good Workaround?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: BLE supports multiple connections, but you can only establish one at a time.  The error seems to indicate that the first connection hasn't actually finished being established (the word "pending").  Perhaps you need to wait for a connection handle on the first connection before trying to establish the 2nd.

Comment: @TimTisdall thanks for your Reply! I changed my Code. I wait till the QLowEnergyController1 emits his connected Signal. After this Signal is emitted I establish the second connection with QLowEnergyController2. The same error occurs.. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: you still get "Cannot connect due to pending active LE Connections"?  That seems really weird if you don't have any left pending.  Sorry, I can't really help further.

Comment: yes still the same error. I think it´s a qt issue..

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't BLE, but its Qt implementation. The documentation says that any attempt to connect simultaneously to two BLE devices using QLowEnergyController will fail. Check it there: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlowenergycontroller.html ; Section "Detailed Description", paragraph 5:
"BlueZ based Linux cannot maintain two connected instances of QLowEnergyController to the same remote device. In such cases the second call to connectToDevice() may fail."

According to this, it should be possible to establish connexion to two different remote devices using two instances of the class, but it simply doesn't work. If you keep on reading the documentation, you'll find out that " This limitation may disappear at some stage in the future.".

I tried a workaround by disconnecting from the first device before connecting to the second device (both TI SensorTag), but since I had to re-discover the services and re-enable the sensors (see disconnectFromDevice() in the documentation) every time I would re-connect the program became way too slow.

If you want to connect to two devices using Qt, you have to use the Bluez API through the D-Bus with Qt's D-Bus classes.

Edit:

I managed to connect to multiple devices using D-Bus classes. The architecture of my program isn't much more complicated, only the syntax got a little more tricky. The only big issue was the BlueZ version: the D-Bus interface changed a lot between 5.3x (default Ubuntu 16.04) that doesn't support Low Energy (experimental...) and later versions. I think that's the reason why Qt's D-Bus Bluetooth hasn' been enabled yet. Since BLE isn't flagged as experimental since BlueZ 5.42, you should be fine using D-Bus with your current version. For the record, I'm perfectly fine using D-Bus with Raspbian's default 5.9 BlueZ.

Comment: could you link the documentation please ?